# Getting data by using SQL Queries and if conditions in Asp

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following tables:

```
SELECT [Cus_ID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Password]
  ,[CNIC]
  ,[Account_No]
  ,[Tel_No]
  ,[Mob_No]
  ,[Website]
  ,[Billing_Address]
  FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Customer]

SELECT [Pay_ID]
  ,[Is_Purchased]
  ,[User_ID]
  ,[Total_Amount]
  ,[Paid_Amount]
  ,[Remaining_Amount]
  ,[Date]
  FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Payments]

SELECT [Bank_ID]
  ,[User_ID]
  ,[Account_No]
  ,[Amount]
  ,[Date]
  FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Bank_Acount]

SELECT [Py_ID]
  ,[User_ID]
  ,[Bank_Name]
  ,[Account_No]
  ,[Date]
  FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Transfer_Pay]
```

I have a transaction page, where i'm doing a simple insertion but with with two conditions.

1). If `Account_No` entered is invalid then it will show us js message that invalid `account_no`.

2). 2nd is if the `total_amount` (which i'm getting from `payments table`) is less than `SUM(Amount)` from `Bank_Acount table` then it must do the insertion process else it shows me the 2nd inner if message that `You have less balance in your Bank Account, Please Deposit the money to purchase again!`.

Here is my whole code i have tried, the main problem i guessed is, i have used a break point on the second inner if condition. Both the queries `Query: 02 and Query: 03`whenever i'm executing it in sql server 2008 R2, they are working 100% correct, but in Visual Studio on debugging mode, it doesn't shows me the values they have. Here is my code.. Please help me. Thank you.

```
int d;
        if (Session["UserCheck"] != null)
        {
            d = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CustomerID"]);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        // Query: 01
        // Getting Account_No from Customers and matching with enterd Account_No in txtAcntNo.Text
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select COUNT(Coalesce(Account_No, '0')) FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Customer] where Account_No = '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "' AND Cus_ID = '"+d+"' ", con);
        con.Open();
        var acc = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();

        // Query: 02
        // Getting Total Amount from User Cart/Order_Details
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Total_Amount] FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Payments] WHERE Date IN (SELECT max(Date) FROM Payments)", con);
        con.Open();
        var T_Ordr_Amount = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();   // Contains Total_Amount from User Cart/Order_Details
        con.Close();

        // Query: 03
        // Getting SUM(Amount) from Bank_Acount Table
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select SUM(Amount) AS T_Amount FROM [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Bank_Acount] where Account_No = '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "' AND User_ID = '" + d + "' ", con);
        con.Open();
        var bnd_acc = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();   // Contains SUM(Amount) from Bank_Acount Table
        con.Close();

        if (acc == "1")      // if  Account_No is matched
        {
            if (bnd_acc > T_Ordr_Amount)      // if SUM(Amount) in Bank_tbl > Total_Amount from Customer_Order_Details
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [NewImport_DB].[dbo].[Transfer_Pay]([User_ID] ,[Bank_Name], [Account_No] ,[Date]) VALUES ('" + d + "' ,'" + txtBnkame.Text + "', '" + txtAcntNo.Text + "', GETDATE())";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Redirect("/shipments.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('You have less balance in your Bank Account, Please Deposit the money to purchase again!')</script>");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('You entered invalid Account No!')</script>");
        }
```

Below are the images... 
[image: 1]

[image: SQL Queries Output in ssms 2]

[image: 3]

[image]

[image: Bank Table data 5]

Comment: This wall of mess is way too much info. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: not to be rude but debugging your code can really save you a lot of headaches it's quite obvious that you are not executing one or more of the query's take your time and make sure that you are executing all query's properly

Comment: So what should i have to do now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at these lines

```
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Total_Amount] FROM .....", con);
con.Open();
var T_Ordr_Amount = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

and

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select SUM(Amount) AS T_Amount FROM ...", con);
con.Open();
var bnd_acc = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

You are always executing `cmd1` instead of `cmd2` and `cmd3`

Apart from this you have a massive problem of security.... NEVER use a string concatenation with the user input to build your sql queries. You are a very easy target for [Sql Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). Use always a [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Comment: cmd 2 and cmd 3 are i just used to get the data sir.. Now i'm totally confused that what should i do now.. :(

Comment: You should execute cmd3.ExecuteScalar and cmd2.ExecuteScalar to get the result from the query text

Comment: is it not executing here `var T_Ordr_Amount = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Yes, I know very well the feeling :-)

Comment: Query No : 02   Error showing Now   Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Probably that SUM(Amount) returns a decimal or a double so casting it to an integer fails. You should check your column datatype

Comment: Yes amount datatype is float

Comment: sir, what should i write here now, i replaced int32 with Decimal, and getting same error

Comment: Decimal is not a float. Try an explicit conversion with _Convert.ToDecimal(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())_ instead of a cast

Comment: OK sir let me try it....

Comment: Thank you so much sir... Done!